# Override template when install module on Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Can I override a Prestashop front template/view (in case order-detail.tpl) during a module installation? I already override controllers putting then on 'my_module/override/**' directory, but isn't working with views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hook `displayOverrideTemplate` to set your own template for front controller.

```
public function hookDisplayOverrideTemplate($params) {
    $controller = $params['controller'];
    if ($controller->php_self == 'order-detail') {
        return 'path_to_your_custom_template.tpl'; 
    }

    return false;
}
```